# Which word to replace this combination?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a list of resources for a role fantasy game. This list contains only the most efficient manufacturable resources.

So far, the list is quite complete. However, it misses a title.
Here is my attempt for naming the list: "Most Efficient Manufacturable Resources".

Which *single* word could be used for removing "Most Efficient"?

Comment: This is a little odd, as resources themselves are usually not "efficient"--they just are, like a lump of coal.  It's the manufacturer or manufacturing that's more or less efficient.

Comment: are the 'Manufacturable' resources resources that get made from raw goods into something that will in turn be used to make something else?

Comment: @Tom22 yes they will

Comment: It's quite a mouthful... "components" is often used as a word for something like that,  Optimal Components .... or Processed Resources (if you want to differentiate between raw and improved resources) might help... if you're looking for a different class of object. Your naming schema really would depend on how stuff is organized.. the suggested answer below "optimal" answers the "most efficient" meaning pretty exactly.

Comment: Maybe what you need is just "Manufacturable resources"--if the player collects a hammer, nails, and wood, he can make table, or something that can be used to make something else.  Or, Raw Materials for Manufacturing Goods and Weapons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to be efficient - the resources, or the manufacturing process.  If you want the resources that can be manufactured most efficiently, you want an adverb to describe "manufacturable."  In that case, you could write:

> **optimally** manufacturable resources.

From [*optimum*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/optimum):

> the greatest degree or best result obtained or obtainable under specific conditions.

In your example sentence, you use "efficient," an adjective, which implies that the described noun is "resources."  So the resources are both "manufacturable" and "efficient."  However, if you want an adjective to describe the resources, you should use a comma to separate it from "manufacturable," as in:

> Most efficient, manufacturable resources.

In that case, you could use "optimal."